# Titanium Android Selectable Text

Tags: android, label, textarea, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am trying to allow selectable text that you can copy and paste on Android, without letting the user edit it or the keyboard appearing. I can't seem to find a way to do this with either label or textarea. Any tips?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try displaying the text using a webView. Check out this nice widget you can use for nice formatting with markdown. (The widget uses a webView)

https://github.com/ricardoalcocer/Ti.MarkdownViewer